# PostgreSQL: Updating attributes of elements in nested arrays within JSONB structure

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-json

I have a jsonb structure in PostgreSQL 9.6 that contains a nested array structure similar to the example below:

```
continents:[
   {
       id: 1,
       name: 'North America',
       countries: [
           {
               id: 1,
               name: 'USA',
               subdivision: [
                  {
                     id: 1,
                     name: 'Oregon',
                     type: 'SOME_TYPE'
                  }
               ]
           } 
       ]
   }
]
```

How can I change the 'type' attribute of multiple subdivisions since it its nested within two arrays ( *countries* and *subdivision* )?

I've come across other answers and am able to do so on a record by record basis (assuming table is **map** and jsonb column is **divisions** ):

```
update map
set divisions = jsonb_set( divisions, '{continents,0,countries,0,subdivisions,0,type}', '"STATE"', FALSE);
```

Is there a way to programatically change that attribute for all subdivisions?

I think I'm getting close, I can query all subdivision types using the query below, but am struggling to figure out how to update them:

```
WITH subdivision_data AS (
    WITH country_data AS (
       select continents -> 'countries' as countries
       from  map, jsonb_array_elements( map.divisions -> 'continents' ) continents
    )
    select country_item -> 'subdivisions' as subdivisions
    from country_data cd, jsonb_array_elements( cd.countries ) country_item
)
select subdivision_item ->> 'type' as subdivision_type
from subdivision_data sub, jsonb_array_elements( sub.subdivisions ) subdivision_item;
```

Here's some of the questions I came across. They seem to work only if you are trying to update a single level array though:

[postgresql 9.5 using jsonb_set for updating specific jsonb array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996212/postgresql-9-5-using-jsonb-set-for-updating-specific-jsonb-array-value)

[How to update deeply nested JSON object based on filter criteria in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035597/how-to-update-deeply-nested-json-object-based-on-filter-criteria-in-postgres)

[Postgres/JSON - update all array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276968/postgres-json-update-all-array-elements)

Comment: speed is not much of a concern since I don't intend on updating this structure often.

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought that something like this would work:

```
update map as m set
    divisions = jsonb_set(m1.divisions, array['continents',(d.rn-1)::text,'countries',(c.rn-1)::text,'subdivisions',(s.rn-1)::text,'type'], '"STATE"', FALSE)
from map as m1,
    jsonb_array_elements(m1.divisions -> 'continents') with ordinality as d(data,rn),
    jsonb_array_elements(d.data -> 'countries') with ordinality as c(data,rn),
    jsonb_array_elements(c.data -> 'subdivisions') with ordinality as s(data,rn)
where
    m1.id = m.id
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7a4411c9dfb45020fff9712c8cc574a7)

But this does't work - see [`documentation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the
>   target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and
>   each output row of the join represents an update operation for the
>   target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces
>   at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a
>   target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other
>   table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to
>   update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily
>   predictable.

What you can do is unnest your jsons with [`functions-json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html) and then aggregate them back:

```
update map set
    divisions = jsonb_set(divisions, array['continents'],
        (select
            jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(
                d, array['countries'],
                (select 
                    jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(
                        c, array['subdivisions'],
                        (select
                            jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(s, array['type'], '"STATE"', FALSE))
                        from jsonb_array_elements(c -> 'subdivisions') as s),
                        FALSE
                    ))
                from jsonb_array_elements(d -> 'countries') as c)
            ))
        from jsonb_array_elements(divisions -> 'continents') as d),
        FALSE
    )
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=37bb9f8f045557da66704ac3575587cb)

You can also create helper function which you can use instead of multiple subqueries:

```
create function jsonb_update_path(_data jsonb, _path text[], _value jsonb)
returns jsonb
as $$
begin
    if array_length(_path, 1) = 1 then
        return jsonb_set(_data, _path, _value, FALSE);
    else
        return (
            jsonb_set(
                _data, _path[1:1],
                (
                    select
                        jsonb_agg(jsonb_update_path(e, _path[2:], _value))
                    from jsonb_array_elements(_data -> _path[1]) as e
                )
            )
        );
    end if;
end
$$
language plpgsql

update map set
    divisions = jsonb_update_path(divisions, '{continents,countries,subdivisions,type}', '"STATE"')
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=85f95d0b68bee4611c82ebebed042b50)

Comment: Spent half a day on a similar problem and and finally found this. I like the fact to you provided a generalisation, it really helps understanding. Such a great answer 

Answer (score 0):

1 general way to do this would be to *explode* the json, replace values using plain old sql & aggregate back to the original json shape. But this requires you to have full knowledge of the document structure

Here's an example of this in a self-contained select statement

```
WITH data(map) AS (
VALUES(JSONB '{"continents":[{"id": 1,"name": "North America","countries": [{"id": 1,"name": "USA","subdivision": [{"id": 1,"name": "Oregon","type": "SOME_TYPE"}]}]}]}')
)
, expanded AS (
SELECT 
  (continents#>>'{id}')::int continent_id
, continents#>>'{name}' continent_name 
, (countries#>>'{id}')::int country_id
, countries#>>'{name}' country_name
, (subdivisions#>>'{id}')::int subdivision_id
, subdivisions#>>'{name}' subdivision_name
, CASE WHEN subdivisions#>>'{type}' = 'SOME_TYPE'      -- put all update where conditions here
        AND continents#>>'{name}' = 'North America'    -- this is where the value is changed
  THEN 'POTATO' 
  ELSE subdivisions#>>'{type}' 
  END subdivision_type
FROM data
, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(map#>'{continents}') continents
, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(continents#>'{countries}') countries
, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(countries#>'{subdivision}') subdivisions
)
, subdivisions AS (
SELECT continent_id
, continent_name
, country_id
, country_name
, JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('subdivisions', JSONB_AGG(JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('id', subdivision_id, 'name', subdivision_name, 'type', subdivision_type))) subdivisions
FROM expanded
GROUP By 1, 2, 3, 4
)
, countries AS (
SELECT
  continent_id
, continent_name
, JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('countries', JSONB_AGG(JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('id', country_id, 'name', country_name, 'subdivision', subdivisions))) countries
FROM subdivisions
GROUP BY 1, 2
)
SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('continents', JSONB_AGG(JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('id', continent_id, 'name', continent_name, 'countries', countries))) map
FROM countries
```

Putting this into an update query, we get the following, where I'm assuming the source table is called `data`, and it has a unique column called `id`

```
UPDATE data SET map = updated.map
FROM (
expanded AS (
SELECT data.id data_id 
, (continents#>>'{id}')::int continent_id
, continents#>>'{name}' continent_name 
, (countries#>>'{id}')::int country_id
, countries#>>'{name}' country_name
, (subdivisions#>>'{id}')::int subdivision_id
, subdivisions#>>'{name}' subdivision_name
, CASE WHEN subdivisions#>>'{type}' = 'SOME_TYPE' 
        AND continents#>>'{name}' = 'North America' 
  THEN 'POTATO' 
  ELSE subdivisions#>>'{type}' 
  END subdivision_type
FROM data
, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(map#>'{continents}') continents
, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(continents#>'{countries}') countries
, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(countries#>'{subdivision}') subdivisions
)
, subdivisions AS (
SELECT
  data_id
, continent_id
, continent_name
, country_id
, country_name
, JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('subdivisions', JSONB_AGG(JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('id', subdivision_id, 'name', subdivision_name, 'type', subdivision_type))) subdivisions
FROM expanded
GROUP By 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
)
, countries AS (
SELECT
  data_id
, continent_id
, continent_name
, JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('countries', JSONB_AGG(JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('id', country_id, 'name', country_name, 'subdivision', subdivisions))) countries
FROM subdivisions
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
)
SELECT data_id, JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('continents', JSONB_AGG(JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('id', continent_id, 'name', continent_name, 'countries', countries))) map
FROM countries
GROUP BY 1

) updated
WHERE updated.data_id = data.id
```